# Word Office add-in SSO is not working inside Microsoft Teams Application

Tags: office-js, office-addins

I am new to Creation Office Add-in using Office JS, I have created a simple Office word add-in by following the Microsoft article.https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/develop/create-sso-office-add-ins-nodejs. The Add-in is working fine with Desktop and Web. But Whenever I try to open the word add-in from the Microsoft Teams Client application, it is prompting me to Popup with Allow and ignore button with Message Add-in trying to open a new page, On click of allow it opens a Blank browser page. After that, it does not redirect to the add-in.

As per the further understanding/debugging of the code, the word office add-in authentication is not working. The "Getaccesstoken method is not supported", inside teams, I have tried to add another token method by following the article:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/msal-js-sso.
Please guide what is how we can authenticate the Add-in inside Microsoft Teams application

Answer (score 0):

When `getAccessToken` is called in a document that is opened in the Teams client, it returns error 13012. Your code should respond to this error by branching to a fallback login strategy. The official documentation for Single Sign-on in Office Add-ins explains how to do this and links to sample add-ins that do this. For one example, see [Office Add-in NodeJS SSO](https://github.com/OfficeDev/Office-Add-in-samples/tree/main/Samples/auth/Office-Add-in-NodeJS-SSO/Complete).